# Installing Gstreamer 0.10 in windows for python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, gstreamer

all i want to do is very simple

installing gstreamer0.10 in windows for python 2.7

please show me a right Detailed way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You must install Gstreamer SDK for Windows - [download page](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+the+SDK), then install Python 2.7 - [this link](https://www.python.org/downloads/), after complette installation, You must configure system environment variable PYTHONPATH. Add Python libs, located in GStreamer directory such as C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86\lib\python2.7\site-packages. Write code. That's all.

Regards

Comment: Should i choose the development packages or the run time packages

Comment: The problem that i didn't find that directory in the development SDK files i will try now the runtime files